# Publish a test website in IIS windows 10

Tags: asp.net, iis

For testing/learning purposes I've been trying to publish a website(build in asp.net) in IIS on windows 10. I enabled everything, made everything as saw on Microsoft tutorials, and youtube tutorials, yet, it seems its not working.

I try to access it thru the Site name I specified, and IP. but its not working.
this is the error keep getting
"This site can’t be reached

projectmms.com’s server DNS address could not be found."

NOTE: projectmms.com is the name/url I specified for the website.

Why is this error keep showing up? I made everything as seen in those tutorials.
and have checked many answers here from other posts, followed the same suggestion and nothing is working. Any suggestion?

EDIT:
after made what few of you requested, this is what I get. This is not my asp.net website.
even tried projectmms.com/default.aspx , it shows that it didn't found the page.
 any help?
[This is what shows now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkSmB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add projectmms.com in your hosts file.

add this in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\host

projectmms.com          **Your_Server_IP_Address**

That will work locally.

Comment: yes, I made it, can you see what it shows now? still error

Comment: Can you execute a ping to projectmms.com with cmd and see what IP address you got.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add projectmms.com domain to your host file (windows\system32\drivers\etc\host) and forward to your local IP (127.0.0.1).

Comment: hi, you mean I need to add the files of the published website into that directory?

Comment: hi again, the Hosts file is iCalendar file. and the rest are just file type, which I can not open.
the only accessible file is Hosts... and can open only with Microsoft Outlook. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, not a reply as you give us little to no info.(but I need 50 rep in order to do so)

- Is the IIS in your machine or a remote one.
- Did you add the name in the DNS server or the HOSTS file.
- Do you reach the machine by ping (hostname/ip)?
- Did you start the ISS service?

P.S.Ask if you don't understand any of the above points.

Comment: hi. Yes, IIS is on my machine, 
I guess I add the DNS when added the website in ISS manager.
yes, I successfully pinged it with hostname, and IP. 
and yes started the service.

please, check the edit of the new post I made for what it shows now.

Comment: It looks like the IIS is working fine, that webpage is the default one when you just install the IIS, the problem might be on the deployment (publish) of the website. Does your site appear in the IIS admin pannel?

Comment: yes it does. but there I cant change the default page.

Comment: They explain how to change the folder route on [this serverfault question](http://serverfault.com/a/411210) also, overall this question might be better fitted for that community :)

Answer (score 0):

Using IIS Express you can only local host access, you have come to enable IIS on Windows resources?

see 
http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later

Comment: Hi, yes I''ve done it all. those are the tutorials I followed